# .htaccess RewriteRule Not Working with Apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know there are a million posts about this, but I have read through a lot of them and made so many changes to get this to work, but I am at a loss. I have setup a redirect rule in my apache2 server web server, but  it does not redirect.

My web server root folder structure:

```
/var/www/example/
|
|----l
     |
     |---index.php
     |---.htaccess
```

**/var/www/example/l/.htaccess content is:**

```
$ cat /var/www/example/l/.htaccess 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^l/([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ l/index.php?redirect=$1 [R=302,L]
```

I have also tried putting it in the root folder `/var/www/example/.htaccess`

My rewrite rule appears to be working correctly from this site:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=6cae684f-740d-4add-b711-53cdb5986681

mod_rewrite.so is installed and rewrite_module is loaded.

I ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and it was turned on

APache2.conf:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory "/var/www/example">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When ever I go to https://example.com/l/i4Ikn2 I just get a 404 error.

I just want to know if I am missing something or somewhere to look. I checked the apache2 `error.log` and there are no error in there pertaining to this.

Comment: The directive you posted certainly won't work if placed in the `/l/.htaccess` file, however, it should "do something" in the root `.htaccess` file (although it will result in a malformed redirect by itself). What other directives do you have? Presumably this should be a rewrite, not a redirect? Any other `.htaccess` files? "made so many changes" - ???

Comment: Inside `i/.htaccess` your ruke should be: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ index.php?redirect=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: AH! you both are wonderful. Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: Just to add... "My rewrite rule appears to be working correctly from this site" - "that site" _assumes_ your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, not a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mrwhite and @anubhava mentioned in the comments below my OP, I was mixing up the way my .htaccess file was being used.

I removed the sub-directory flags (the `l` in the pattern) and added the `QSA` instead of the redirect (`R=302`).
This was because I was using the .htaccess file in the sub-directory.
The QSA was the correct 'option' for the redirect/rewrite (still unsure of the difference).

Original:

```
RewriteRule ^l/([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ l/index.php?redirect=$1 [R=302,L]
```

New (working):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ index.php?redirect=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The `QSA` flag (Query String Append) simply appends the original query string (if any) that was on the initial request to the query string you have stated in the _substitution_ string. If you are not expecting a query string on the initial request, then the `QSA` flag should be removed. eg. With the `QSA` flag, if you request `example.com/l/i4Ikn2?foo=bar` then your rewrite will result in `/l/index.php?redirect=i4Ikn2&foo=bar`. Without `QSA` then `foo=bar` is not appended.